# Defaulted special member function with external definition

Tags: c++, constructor

I would like to declare a `class` with a defaulted constructor<sup>1</sup>, but I want to this defaulted constructor to be "extern" in the sense the constructor body should only be compiled once, when the TU for the class is compiled, and not in each TU that includes that header. Finally, the class should should not be seen to have a user-provided constructor, but rather a defaulted one<sup>2</sup>.

For example, here's one attempt:

**foo.hpp:**

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
};
```

**foo.cpp:**

```cpp
Foo::Foo() = default;
```

This results in a defaulted constructor implementation, but it means that `Foo` has a user-provded constructor, which affects the traits of the type, e.g., whether it is trivial, etc.

Here's another way:

**foo.hpp:**

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() = default;
};
```

This preserves the "not user-provided" property, but now every TU that includes this class and uses the constructor will generate machine code for it (and this code might get inlined, etc).

---

<sup>1</sup> Really, this applies to any special member functions, but I'm using the default constructor here for concreteness.

<sup>2</sup> Whether the class has a user-provided constructor affects various important traits and behaviors of the class, such as whether it has a [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor) constructor, whether other special member functions are implicitly deleted or not, etc.

Comment: a "default constructor" is one that can be called without parameters, it is not necessarily a compiler generated one

Comment: Why do you care that every TU is generating the code for it? The performance impact here is minimal

Comment: @idclev463035818, yes I should have said _defaulted default constructor_. Let me fix up the next.

Comment: @MooingDuck - lol. How do you know?

Comment: it is clear from the text what you want, but title and some sentences are asking for a default constructor

Comment: @idclev463035818 - I think I've cleared it up now, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Either have a user declared constructor and define it externally, or have explicitly/implicitly default constructor inline. Neither satisfies your all wants and there are no other options. You'll need to decide which you want more. You are essentially asking for: "I want everyone to know how the constructor is defined, but no one must know how it is defined.

Comment: Nitpicking: `Foo() = default;` (in class body) *is* user-declared. It's not user-provided though.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - I didn't find the word provided, but changed one place where I said "user-defined" to "user-declared". I think that's what you were referring to, right?

Comment: @MooingDuck If you are writing a shared library and no actual constructor is emitted, adding one later will cause ABI issues (applications compiled against the old definition will not call the constructor, just do the default construction inline). To work around this, one can always declare a empty constructor body, but that have the 'user-declared' problem mentioned in the question

Comment: @BeeOnRope No. If I understand your post correctly, you're saying that `Foo() = default;` (in class body) is similar to letting the compiler generate the constructor, in the sense that the ctor is "not user-declared" (but the right word is "not user-provided").

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - thanks, after brushing up on that topic, I get what you are saying. I've updated the question to clarify that the important distinction is whether the constructor is _user-provided_ or not.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way in the *language* to tell the compiler that a function is non-user-provided (“you know everything about it”) while also claiming that it’s opaque (“you can’t do the code generation here”).  Fortunately, the obvious implementation strategy for C++20 **modules** has that effect: a member function defaulted in its class in a module interface unit will be considered for inlining everywhere but obviously needs only one out-of-line copy in the object file generated for the module.

If you want a stronger guarantee than that, you’re well into implementation-specific territory and you should look into compiler-specific attributes to govern code generation.